# Creating an Avro file in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, avro

How to create an Avro file in s3 bucket and then appending avro records to it.

I have all the avro records in the form of Byte array and were successfully transferred in an avro file. But his file is (what i know) not a complete avro file. Since a complete avro file is schema + data.

Following is the code to transfer the byte records in a file in S3.

Any one knows how to create a avro schema based file and then transfer these bytes to that same file.

```
public void sendByteData(byte [] b, Schema schema){
        try{
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXX", "XXXXXX");

            AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

            //createFolder("encounterdatasample", "avrofiles", s3Client);


            ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
             meta.setContentLength(b.length);
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);

        /*  File file = new File("/home/abhishek/sample.avro");
            DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
            DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(writer);
            dataFileWriter.create(schema, file); 
            s3Client.putObject("encounterdatasample", dataFileWriter.create(schema, file), stream, meta); 
         */

            s3Client.putObject("encounterdatasample", "sample.avro", stream,meta);
            System.out.println("Done writing the data");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The code in comments doesn't work. Was just trying to play around with it.
Any help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your assertion is correct, you can't encode both the data and the schema in the byte array.  You need to use some container, typically a file, to encode both.

With a few fixes, the code you have commented out should work.  I just did something similar from within a Lambda written in Java.  I wrote the file out to local disk (`/tmp`) using `DataFileWriter`, then put that file to S3 using your syntax without issue.

Two suggestions:

- call `dataFileWriter.close()` once you're finished writing to file.
- use the `file` object directly in the `s3Client.putObject` call, e.g. `s3Client.putObject(bucket,key,file)`